# fastapi websocket erro on insert

Tags: websocket, fastapi

I'm trying to use a websocket to trigger my inserts.
I just mock some data to illustrate

router.py

```
@core.post('/add')
async def proceed_next(db: Session = Depends(get_database)):
    new = await TestRepo(db).process()
    return new
```

repository.py

```
class TestRepo:
    def __init__(self, database: Session):
        self.database = database

    async def process(self):

        mocked_data = MyModel(
            client='client',
            number='number'
        )

        self.database.add(mocked_data)
        self.database.commit()
        self.database.refresh(mocked_data)
        return mocked_data
```

works, is inserted

Now i trying add a websocket from frontend to start this process(Insert data).

I remove my decorator @core.post('/add') from function proceed_next.
And add another function that call function proceed_next

```
@core.websocket('/client-ws')
async def client_socket(websocket: WebSocket):

    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()

        m = await proceed_next()
```

And i get this error:
**self.database.add(mocked_data)

AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'add'

INFO:     connection closed**

can someone explain to me why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `Depends()` parameters in a path operation function or in other dependencies. Just having `async def proceed_next(db: Session = Depends(get_database)):` without the decorator, means it's just a function (not a path operation function) and the magic of FastAPI's DI system is not applied. `Depends()` objects are only solved in the context of a request.

Comment: i move Depends to websocket function and pass (db) in context